# Truncating Fields in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Having an issue with field names not getting truncated.  I'm displaying a leader board on a site, and players with long names are breaking the table.  I tried the below, but to no avail.  Hoping someone can help!

```
select 
    case
        when char_length('player_name') >= 13 then left('player_name', 12) + '...'
        else player_name
    end player_name,
    case
        when char_length('squad') >= 10 then left('squad', 10)
        else squad
    end squad,
    pub_rank
from
    database.player_rank
order by pub_rank desc
limit 10;
```

Here is some sample data. I add row #'s in PHP. Some players won't have a squad.

`player_name    squad   player_rank
Kalu    1st line    106.70
Jugu    Cobra   96.29
BOG Blood   87.52
vai cavalo      87.09
Ebony&Ivory Bury    85.80
Taunt   BlameTaunt  83.44
7461756e74207375636     82.98
Tut     82.03
baddreams       81.09
Tryo    Team Gluten 80.40`
`

Please and thanks!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: The columns in your data have different names than the columns in your query

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted from the site. I used pretty name.  I've updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks around your columns. Use concat() to concatenate the value and string.

```
select 
    case when char_length(`player_name`)>=13 
        then CONCAT(left(`player_name`, 12), '...') 
    else player_name end player_name, 

    case when char_length(`squad`)>=10 
        then left(`squad`, 10) 
    else squad end squad, 

pub_rank from database.player_rank 
order by pub_rank desc limit 10;
```

**edit:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc789/3 I built this fiddle with a query. Might have changed some names and used other numbers for the query, but it shows what has to be done -> concat() for concatenating and "`" for the tablenames

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  I'm getting 0 results now when i try to use the above...

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Sure. I've updated the main question with some sample data.

Comment: added a fiddle to the answer, feel free to adjust the data according to yours if I got something wrong

Comment: Thanks @Philipp. Looks like I was didn't copy/paste correctly.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> select  if( char_length('player_name')>=13, left('player_name', 12) ,
>   player_name) from database.player_rank  order by pub_rank desc limit
>   10;

And use one if for one condition

Comment: Same result as @phillips response.  I now get 0 results.